# v-checkbox weird behavior when using with v-for in Vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, checkbox, vuetify.js

I am using **Vue2** and **Vuetify2**. I have some checkboxes created using a `v-for` loop. All checkboxes are inside a dialog component.

**The Procedure-**

1. Before opening the dialog, I make an API request and fetch the items. Then, I open the dialog and select the checkboxes.
2. Before closing the dialog, I empty the `selected` array, so I will have no items selected on opening the dialog again.

**The issue-**
When I open the dialog a second time, all checkboxes are already selected even though the variable `selected` is set to an empty array `[]`. Then if I try to unselect any item,  all are unselecting together and after that only one at a time is selectable.

Here is the working demo of this issue-

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <v-app>
        <v-btn dark @click.stop="onBeforeOpen">
          Open Dialog
        </v-btn>
        <div class="mt-5">{{ msg }}</div>
        <div class="mt-5">Selected items - {{ selected }}</div>
        <v-dialog v-model="dialog" persistent>
          <v-card class="pa-5">
            <div><b>Select items and close dialog.</b></div>
            <v-checkbox
              v-for="item in items"
              :key="item.id"
              v-model="selected"
              :value="item"
              >
              <template v-slot:label>
                <v-card flat>
                  <div>{{ item.name }}</div>
                  <div>{{ item.email }}</div>
                </v-card>
              </template>
            </v-checkbox>
            <div align="center">
              <v-btn color="error" small @click="onBeforeClose"
                >Close Dialog</v-btn
                >
            </div>
          </v-card>
        </v-dialog>
      </v-app>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
    <script>
      new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        vuetify: new Vuetify(),
        data () {
          return {
            dialog: false,
            selected: [],
            items: null,
            msg: null,
          }
        }, 
        methods: {
          onBeforeOpen() {
             this.msg = "Fetching items from API....";
             $.ajax("https://gorest.co.in/public/v2/users", {
              success: (data, status, xhr) => {
                this.items = data.splice(0, 2);
                this.msg = null;
                this.dialog = true
              },
             });
          },
          onBeforeClose() {
            this.selected = [];
            this.dialog = false;
          }
        }
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT-**

If I use `:value="item.id"`, the checkboxes are working fine. But I need to return the whole item object, not only the id, so I have to use `:value="item"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound like a bug... The first time the check box is displayed, it work fine... but the second time, it act like the v-model has a object (not array) and has the simple selection behavior.

You can force the multiple behavior with the prop [multiple](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-checkbox/#props-multiple) :

```html
<v-checkbox
  v-for="item in items"
  :key="item.id"
  v-model="selected"
  :value="item"
  multiple
>
```

Comment: It's so strange, I tried it before but it didn't work but now it worked. Also, I am passing an object to the value prop, and I read the discussion on GitHub which said that passing an object as a value in the v-checkbox is a bug because of passing reference of an object that needs to be fixed manually.

Comment: Anyhow the multiple props worked. Thanks very much, @vernou.

Comment: The bug isn't present in Vuetify3.

Comment: I opened [a issue](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/16360) on GitHub about this bug.